# How to create jumbotron/hero with chevron cutout background image/colour on one side?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, background-image

How can I achieve a hero/jumbotron section with a background image on the right-hand side which has a chevron cutout on its left side?

See the below mock-up...

[image]

Here is my HTML mark-up for the section minus any background image, below. I am using Bootstrap 4. Answers adhering to that are favourable...

```
<div class="jumbotron-fluid bg-dark d-flex  text-white  px-3" style="height:400px; ">

    <div class="container align-self-center pl-0">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="align-self-center col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-5 col-xl-12 pb-5">
                <h5>Blurb goes here</h5>

                <h1 class="display-4 pb-3">Jumbotron</h1>

                <p class="lead text-muted pb-0 mb-0">Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

The likely answer involves adding a second column, `.col-lg-7`, and applying the effect to that, rather than applying the effect to the whole of `.jumbotron`.

A secondary variant should allow the right-column Bootstrap colour `bg-danger` (red) to be show through, rather than an image...

[image]

I don't want to manually edit an image to introduce a transparency; I want this done in HTML/CSS.

Comment: this problem is related to CSS and where is the CSS?

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet